# Tensorflow speech-commands recognize scores

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, speech-recognition, tensorflow.js

I have a `recognizer` and used its `listen` function to get the `Float32Array` array from [`SpeechCommandRecognizerResult.spectrogram.data`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/speech-commands/src/types.ts#L367), then concatenated the array using [`concatenateFloat32Arrays`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/2d269c257bf59a3c878d823d3e3973d7954500bc/speech-commands/src/generic_utils.ts#L45) util function

The scores (`SpeechCommandRecognizerResult.scores`) were **`normalized`** when using `listen` function, but when I use [`recognize`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/speech-commands/src/types.ts#L85) function and provide a `Float32Array` as an `input`, the scores are **`not normalized`**

How to get a `normalized` `scores` using `recognize` function with an `input` of `Float32Array`?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you put in a normalized array doesn't mean it will come out that way. It looks like the recognizer outputs word probabilities for the input audio from `listen`. From the code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/speech-commands/src/types.ts#L367)

```js
export interface SpeechCommandRecognizerResult {
  /**
   * Probability scores for the words.
   */
  scores: Float32Array|Float32Array[];
```

While probabilities are usually normalized, this neural network's output probabilities are probably only used in comparison to each other to determine which word it is. Find the maximum index of the output array to get the word that it's predicting.